# AS3 - Compress ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, compression, arrays, base64

Out of a drawing I'm generating a PNG and upload it as a Base64 string via PHP to my server.
Is it possible to compress the Base64 string in AS3?

This is my code:

```
var png:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(b);
var myimage:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(png);
```

I was hoping to speed things up a little.
Thanks for any informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PNG data is [already compressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).  You could attempt to manually compress the Base64 data, but you will end up with binary data again, and the result cannot be any smaller than the original image data was.  If your server can accept binary data, then you will save the most space by skipping the Base64 encoding and just shipping the raw image data.

Alternately, you could try encoding your image as a JPEG instead of a PNG, which will let you further reduce the size of the data, albeit at the expense of image quality.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code could help you:

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.utils.Base64Decoder; //Transform String in a ByteArray.
import mx.utils.Base64Encoder; //Transform ByteArray in a readable string.
import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder; //Encode a BitmapData in a PNG;

var myBMD:BitmapData=new myBitmapData(0,0); //In this case I had a BitmapData in the library so I took it from there.

var myBMDByteArray:ByteArray=(new PNGEncoder).encode(myBMD); //Create the ByteArray of myBMD usinf the PNGEncoder.

var compStr:String=compress(myBMDByteArray); //Creates String
trace(compStr);

// The loader acts exactly as we were loading an external PNG except the fact that we 
write the ByteArray.

var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.loadBytes(uncompress(compStr)); // In the loadBytes we write the Base64 String of the image.

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void

{

    var bmp:BitmapData=new BitmapData(loader.width,loader.height,true,0x0);

    bmp.draw(loader);

    addChild(new Bitmap(bmp));

}


// Compress a ByteArray into a Base64 String.

function compress(bytes:ByteArray):String 

{

    var enc:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();    
    enc.encodeBytes(bytes);
    return enc.drain().split("\n").join("");
}

// Uncompress a Base64 String into a ByteArray.

function uncompress(str:String):ByteArray 
{

    var dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();

    dec.decode(str);

    var newByteArr:ByteArray=dec.toByteArray();        

    return newByteArr;
}
```